# Detect if i'm allowed to play video on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have a dynamic element on the page that in certain situations will have a video (Vimeo). The jQuery code checks if the element excists and adds video itself and the play on hover.

This works (tested on Chrome & Firefox) after you have interacted with the website. Before you interact, you run into the autoplay policies, a good thing in my opinion, and the console will tell you the action is not allowed.
You might get around this with muting the video. But the contents are about a person explaining something. So without the sound it loses a lot of its value. So would like to keep that in.

As said, these policies are a good thing in my opinion, so I do not want a way around it or a way to trick it into playing anyway. I would like to add some other functionality when the site is in this 'state'(?). Add a button or some other incentive to interact with the site and play the video. But if not in this 'state' I would like to keep the play on hover.

Is there a way I can detect this state?

I see another question, almost the same issue: [Is there an event to detect when user interacted with a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52163817/is-there-an-event-to-detect-when-user-interacted-with-a-page)
But the solutions there are not answers to the problem, like trying it with an interval until it works... creative, but not something I'm looking for.

Here is in short what I have now. And what is missing.

```
...video settings...

if ($('#vidcontainer').length) {
  var videoPlayer = new Vimeo.Player('vidcontainer', options);

  ...
  if state is 'allow hover' { 
  ...

  $("#vidcontainer").mouseover(function () {
    videoPlayer.play();
  }).mouseout(function () {
    videoPlayer.pause();
  });

  ... 
  } else if state is 'not allowd hover'  { 
       ... do something else ...
  } 
...
}
```

Comment: Play on hover I would consider massively annoying to begin with. That is not what I would expect as a user, and if it even starts blaring sounds based on just _that_ ... yikes.

Comment: Agree with you on that. But client wants this, even after telling them it is not really user friendly.